# trigonometric limit using identities

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

"find"
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{6x+5x^2}{\tan(4x)}$$
saso what I've tried so far is splitting the *$\tan(4x)$* into $\sin(4x)/\cos(4x)$ and try to get to an identity, the ones im allowed to use as identities are

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin (x)}{x} =1$$ $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos (x)}{x} =0$$

please help me find it without using l'Hopital.

Comment: The second identity is not true. $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos{(x)}}{x}=0$

Comment: @PeterForemanyou're right!!! sorry  I just edited it

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Just write

$$\frac{6x+5x^2}{\tan{(4x)}} = \cos{(4x)}\cdot \frac{4x}{4\sin{(4x)}}\cdot(6+5x)$$

Comment: oh, ok so after multiplying by 1 (4/4) I then just past the lower part (1/4) to one of the other two factors, $$\frac{6+5x}{4}$$ then plugging 0 in gives $$1*1*\frac{3}{2}$$
thank you very much, very useful hint

Comment: Yes. You can (almost) do that. But note that you cannot plug in $0$ in $\frac{4x}{\sin (4x)}$. But you can take the limit which is $1$. In the other expressions you can plug in $0$ indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{6x+5x^2}{\tan(4x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{\frac{\sin{(4x)}}{4x}}\times\cos(4x)\times\left(\frac32+\frac{5x}4\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Well by examining the Taylor series expansion of $\tan{(x)}$ we have another 'small angle approximation' that is
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan{(x)}}{x}=1$$
So we can solve this limit by dividing through by $4x$ giving
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\frac32+\frac54x}{\left(\frac{\tan{(4x)}}{4x}\right)}=\frac32$$

Answer (score 0):

We can use the series expansion of $\tan(x)$:
$$
\tan(x)=x+\frac{1}{3}x^3+\ldots
$$
Ignoring higher order infinitesimals, we get
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{6x+5x^2}{4x+\frac{1}{3}\times64x^3}=\frac{6x}{4x}=1.5.
$$